# Angular 2 dynamic append and onclick

Tags: angular

I have three angular 2 component.

ModalComponent:

```
import {Component, DynamicComponentLoader, Injector, ApplicationRef, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {TextContentComponent} from "./contents/text-content.component";
import {LinkContentComponent} from "./contents/link.content.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'js-popup-container',
    template: `
        <style>
            .display-block {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
        <div [ngClass]="'display-block'" id="js-popup-container" class="css-popup-container">
            <h1>Select</h1>
            <select name="selectContent" id="select" #sel (change)="selectedContent(sel.value)">
                <option value="one">Picture</option>
                <option value="two">Link</option>
                <option value="three">Text</option>
            </select>
            <div id="load">

            </div>
            <p>{{value}} error here.</p>
        </div>

    `,
    inputs: ['itemBack']
})

export class ModalComponent {
    @Input() itemBack;
    value = this.itemBack; // Why doesn't it work?

    constructor(public dcl:DynamicComponentLoader, public injector:Injector, private appRef:ApplicationRef) {
    }

    selectedContent(Selected:string) {
        switch (Selected) {
            case 'one':
                break;
            case 'two':
                this.loadContent(LinkContentComponent);
                break;
            case 'three':
                this.loadContent(TextContentComponent);
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    loadContent(ComponentType) {
        this.dcl.loadAsRoot(ComponentType, '#load', this.injector)
            .then(componentRef => {
                //componentRef.instance.itemBack = this.itemBack;
                (<any>this.appRef)._loadComponent(componentRef);
            });
    }

}
```

LinkContentComponent:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'link-content',
    template: `
        <div class="input">
            <label for="link-content-text">Link</label>
            <input type="text" id="link-content-text" [(ngModel)]="item.text">
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="bbk" (click)="contentTextSave()">Save</a>
    `,
    outputs: ['itemBack']
})

export class LinkContentComponent {
    item = {text: ''};
    itemBack = new EventEmitter<{text: string}>();
    contentTextSave(){
        this.itemBack.emit(this.item);
    }
}
```

TextContentComponent

```
import {Component, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'text-content',
    template: `
        <div class="input">
            <label for="text-content-text">Text</label>
            <input type="text" id="text-content-text" [(ngModel)]="item.text">
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="bbk" (click)="contentTextSave()">Save</a>
    `,
    outputs: ['itemBack']
})

export class TextContentComponent {
    item = {text: ''};
    itemBack = new EventEmitter<{text: string}>();
    contentTextSave(){
        this.itemBack.emit(this.item);
    }
}
```

The ModalComponent is the important bit the rest is just there to see what is in the component. The code actually brings up a pop up window.

You can clearly see the problem right here: `<p>{{value}} error here.</p>` - It doesn't really show anything.

This is where it should get the `value: value = this.itemBack;` which comes from an input.
The `loadAsRoot` is probably not loading the inputs properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update**

```
loadContent(ComponentType) {
    this.dcl.loadAsRoot(ComponentType, '#load', this.injector)
        .then(componentRef => {
            //componentRef.instance.itemBack = this.itemBack;
              componentRef.instance.itemBack.subscribe(value => {
                this.itemBack = value;
              });
            (<any>this.appRef)._loadComponent(componentRef);
        });
}
```

**original**

`@Input()` is not initialized before `ngOnChanges()` is called the first time. `ngOnInit()` is called immediately after `ngOnChanges()` was called the first time and is usually the right place for additional initialization.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.value = this.itemBack; // does work
}
```

I don't know TS very well (I only use Dart) but code like

```
value = this.itemBack;
```

is probably also not valid in TS outside of the constructor or a method because code like this is executed when the class instance is created before the constructor is executed and using `this` before the constructor is usually invalid because the class is not yet fully created and initialization not yet completed.

Comment: I did it, but the value is still empty.

Comment: Actually I don't see you setting `this.itemBack` anywhere. So why do you expect it to have a value?

Comment: @Input() itemBack; This is it.

Comment: This doesn't do anything by itself. This just allows to pass a value using a binding like `<js-popup-container [itemBack]="someValue">`

Comment: Alright, I understand that and it works like that for sure, but I'd like to load the components dinamically. 
But I have a feeling the loadContent(ComponentType) doesn't give back the outputs.

Comment: `@Input()` and `@Output()` are not supported with DCL. Missed that part of the code in `loadContent()`. Have a look at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6370#issuecomment-193896657 With `loadAsRoot()` you have to take care yourself that change detection is run.

Comment: I updated my answer. Using `EventEmitter` this way is discouraged though. It should be changed to a `Subject`/`Observable`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is was a very important information.